# calabash android run with japan text

Tags: calabash-android

I try run Calabash-android test. But i got a trouble.
This is my script test:

Feature: Check Navigation feature

```
Scenario: Click on Navigation button of menu
    When I should see "確認"
    Then I wait for 3 seconds
    Then I press the "OK" button
```

When i exec the test. Command Window show me an error.

"\xE7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding:: UndefinedConversionError) (RuntimeError)

Does any body get same problem? can you tell me how to fix it?

I searched from internet and get a solution

http://ytabuchi.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/02/28/204850.

I do set RUBYOPT=-EUTF-8 command but it does not effect.

My calabash version is 0.5.8
Ruby version is 2.2.0
Windows 7 x64

Comment: +1 for including your Calabash Android version.  Can you provide the exact command you are running and the stack trace that generated the error?   Can you update to Calabash Android 0.5.10?

Comment: calabash android 0.5.10 can not run for android 4.1.1 and android 4.2.2. so i use version 0.5.8 because it more stable.
Btw, I tried ruby version 2.0.0 and it can run as well. So this problem is resolved.